# Getting a textarea to autoexpand when using wysihtml5?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have an html editor on my web page that will autogrow to accommodate the amount of text and formatting entered.

I am using the wysihtml5 Jquery library to get my text box to allow html editing, but I have tried a number of autogrow and expanding plugs to actually get the display to auto re-size.

I understand that the reason they don't is because wysihtml5 attached to a textarea actually creates an iframe that displays the text and hides the actual textarea.

Does anyone know of a way to get an autoexpanding textarea that has html editing?

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS:

```
//Editor {
height: auto;
width: auto;
};
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The styles of the iframe that the editor resides in already has the height set to auto but it does not expand when typing.

Comment: Even on a plain textarea that does not make the textarea expand as you type.